# Performing Aqiqa after Child has become Mature

Tags: sunnah, baby, aqeeqah

If Someone has not done Aqiqa of His Baby after birth so can he perform Aqiqa after His Maturity any time?

Would That be Valid?

JazakAllah.

Comment: As I remarked in my answer, that would be ok after that age. Even as far as I can remember, I red somewhere that do Aqiqah even if you are at the old age. as a consequence, you'd better do it whenever. . . And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum.

There is a hadeeth that says:

> أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: "كل غلام مرتهن بعقيقته، تذبح عنه
>   يوم سابعه، ويحلق ويتصدق بوزن شعره فضة أو ما يعادلها ويسمى"

The best time to perform the Aqeeqa is seventh or fourteenth or twenty first day after the birth.
But, if someone couldn't perform the Aqeeqa in this time due to some difficulties or something else, they can perform it later and there is no hadeeth or statement specifying a limit of time for performing Aqeeqa.

Comment: Waalekumussalam JazakAllah for you answer so can aqeeqa be performed any time during life time like when Kids are grown up now and parents are become old so would that be still valid

Comment: Yes it will be valid

Answer (score 0):

Salam

Aqiqa should be done in childhood, but if someone has not done, he should do it although he is mature, and it is valid.
Fi aman Allah.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

It is declared that Aqiqah is deemed to be a Mustahab-al-Mo’akad (strongly recommended) based on Islam. Even some ulema (learned men) remarked it as a
Wajib (mandatory) practice and it is remarked that it is better to be done at the seventh day of birth. Afterwards, it is said that it is Mustahab (recommended) for the father to do that till the age of puberty. But after that age (till end of the life) it is Mustahab for himself (herself) to perform Aqiqah.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.firouzi.org](http://www.firouzi.org/?p=4198)

Comment: JazakAllah for your Answer.I have read if baby is dead after birth and parents have not performed aqiqah then baby will not intercede for their parents,, is it so.